# WP Как писать IP пользователей которые посещают сайт в лог файл?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот нашел скрипт который отображает IP пользователя при посещении определенной страницы /// Добавляется в `function.php`

```
add_shortcode('show_ip', 'get_the_user_ip');
function get_the_user_ip()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        //check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        //to check ip is pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $currentIP = apply_filters('edd_get_ip', $ip);
    $currentData = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

    $text = $currentData." ".$currentIP;

    echo file_put_contents("ipAdress.txt", $text);
}
```

Вызывается через шорткод `[show_ip]`. А как на основе данного плагина сделать такой, что бы считывал IP пользователей, но складывал в какой-то скажем текстовый файл на сервере --- Ну там дата посещения и IP пользователя ?  Определенной страницы...

Comment: Создать обработчик для нужного хука, в него добавить условие для проверки страницы, если условие срабатывает - записывать данные в файл

Comment: Как писать в файл? С датой ?

Comment: Самый простой пример - функция `file_put_contents('путь/к/файлу.расширение', 'данные');`

Comment: Лучше используй серверную статистику (webalizer, awstat и тд) и не грузи движок всякой ерундой.

Comment: @lezhni А можно немного больше подробностей? А то чет, создал а оно не записывает.

Comment: @SeVlad согласен, лучше, только у меня нету доступов к серверу, только WP и его начинка

Comment: Можно код глянуть?

Comment: @lezhni Поменял код в задаче... Оно записывает, но только каждый раз перезатирает файл, а мне бы добавление новой строчки в `ipAdress.txt` Ну и дата у меня как-то не совпадает по часам с реальным временем

Comment: Этот скрипт небезопасен, потому что злоумышленник имеет возможность подсунуть свои собственные значения в HTTP-заголовок `Client-IP` или `X-Forwarded-For` и таким образом «подделать» свой IP-адрес

Comment: Но в любом случае зачем это вообще делать, если любой нормальный веб-сервер и так по умолчанию пишет журнал посещений в какой-нибудь access.log, можно оттуда грепнуть нужную страницу например

Comment: @andreymal У меня не стоит задача, сделать чекалку, или сделать это максимально безопасно, что б оно фильтровало по vpn... У меня элементарная задача - собрать IP адресса всех посетителей определенной веб страницы за сутки.... Я осознаю что это правильнее делать на серверной стороне специально обученными програмами, но как я уже писал выше у меня НЕТУ доступа к веб-серверу, только WP.

Comment: В таком случае лучше всего перенести WP в какое-нибудь другое место, в котором доступ к веб-серверу всё-таки есть

Comment: Касательно «каждый раз перезатирает файл» в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php) пишут, что у file_put_contents есть флаг FILE_APPEND

Comment: Для ВП, кстати есть плагины, собирающие IP. Это будет намного безопаснее, чем править что-то в коде не имея доступа к серверу. Хотя без доступа я бы и плагины не рисковал ставить.